# Shouldn't typescript transpiler at least warn about calling virtual methods from superclass constructor?

Tags: typescript, oop

An important reason to choose Typescript as our design language was the prevention of runtime errors like "X is undefined". However, we still experience a few of those when calling a virtual method from a superclass constructor.

Shouldn't the compiler give an error for this?

The [Typescript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) does not mention that calls to virtual methods are not allowed (more correctly: may not use `this`).

One of the contributors only [suggests](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23020#issuecomment-377537924) to write a tslint rule to check for this, another one labelled it a [Design Limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26643)

```
abstract class Base {
    constructor(protected readonly numbers: number[]) {
        this.initialise()
    }

    protected abstract initialise(): void 
}

class Extended extends Base {
    private readonly squares: number[] = []

    protected initialise() {
        this.numbers.forEach( num => this.squares.push( num * num ) )
    }
}

const extended = new Extended( [1,2,3,4,5] )
```

The code above produces a runtime error (check it on the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). You'll see it will transpile nicely, no errors or even warnings. But when you run it, the console will show an error)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:30:68
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Extended.initialise (<anonymous>:30:22)
    at Extended.Base (<anonymous>:17:14)
    at new Extended (<anonymous>:24:47)
```

The `squares` property of Extended is still undefined when Base's constructor calls the initialise method. This is due to the way the code is converted into Javascript.
Although I can understand the underlying reason, it is very annoying the compiler does not complain about this. I have seen suggestions to do "lazy" initialisation of members like `Extended.squares`, but I very much like keeping members `readonly` as much as possible.

Actually, I would really expect the code below to function correctly (having both the `numbers` and `squares` arrays filled with five numbers). But as long as it is not allowed to use `this` before all super constructors have finished, the compiler should indicate that.

Comment: Typescript has no warnings, only errors (no joke, really). All methods are potentially virtual since you can override them in JS, so this could be at best be an error in a derived class if you override a method that is used in a base constructor, and since this information is not always available (it is only available if you write the base class as well as the derived class) it does not make sense to make  compiler error that only rarely catches an issue (IMO)

Comment: Especially since they may be rare, it should be detected. (IMO) The first time it happened to me, it took quite some debugging before I realised what was happening. In es6, it is more obvious, because then you would have to create the _squares_ array before calling _super()_, which isn't allowed! Since Typescript allows to **create** members with initialisation in the class body, the sequence of execution is no longer obvious.

Comment: My point is that is create a false sense of safety, you can't really detect these unless the code of the base class is in the same project as the derived class.. If you don't have access to the base class code for TS to analyze it can't tell that a method you are overriding is a potential problem

Comment: Then all of Typescript is a false sense of safety. You can always circumvent it. I would even say that calling methods from a constructor should be disallowed. Maybe even have an _initialise()_ method that will get called after `new` has finished the constructors.

Comment: Typescript compiler should really disallow method calls from constructors. Even with private members one could get "Undefined errors" [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20b%3A%20number%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.c()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.b%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20c()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.b.push(1)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20A())

Comment: made it a feature request on [Microsoft / Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30834).